# How do you write to a .dat file in C++?

Tags: c++

If I try something like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream output;
    output.open("message.dat");

    output << "hello";
}
```

I get a message: aggregate 'std::ofstream output' has incomplete type and cannot be defined.

How can I create a .dat file and write to it normally like I would a .txt file?

Comment: Compiles fine for me. `std::ofstream` should be defined as long as you have included `<fstream>`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: If you post a question about any kind of error messages, then please include the *complete* and *unedited* error message in the question, and also tell us where it comes from (compiler? linker? the program at runtime?) The message you provide needs some more context.

Comment: See here for the example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are trying too hard. Here the error isn't that important. He just tries to write to binary files ..

Comment: @yasen But it *isn't* a binary file. Just because the file-name ends in ".dat" doesn't automatically mean it's binary. It's the *open flags* that determines if the file is binary or not, and then just in that program. And there still shouldn't be a problem to use the normal text output operator to write to a binary file.

Comment: The sample code is ok. It compiles on IDEONE. See here http://ideone.com/kbrlx5

Comment: Are there any other include files which are included in this .cpp file? Can you show all of them.
@Victor - agree, it compiles if it is the only code in the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are thinking that `.dat` is a binary file. Okay, it will always depend on what you want to write in that file. I can though provide a general example about writing binary files.

```
ofstream write_file;
write_file = ofstream( this->location, ios::out | ios::binary );

for( size_t i = 0; i != file_size ++i )
{
    // use write_file.write() to add bytes into your binary file.
    // e.g the line below will write empty chars to your binary file
    write_file.write( "", 1 );
}   

write_file.close();
```

See a working code here, on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/KXNIx1).

---

As someone commented, you have to include `<fstream>` to be able to use file streams. I think your errors comes from the misincluding in your file. Also, the `.dat` file is supposed to be binary, as I mentioned above. The prototype of `open()` is:

```
void open (const string& filename,  ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);
// with const &string as parameter since C++11
```

So, as you can see, the `openmode` is set to `ios_base::out` and you should have `ios_base::binary | ios_base::out`

Comment: The sample code has the line
#include<fstream>